# Time out exception when accessing Connectship web service through progistic AMP

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, ups

I am implementing a shipping application for a client. In order to ship via UPS carrier client wants us to use Connectship web services. [Progistics AMP](http://www.connectship.com/Products/AMP/) API is used to communicate with Connectship web services.
while installing connectship tool kit it creates a AMP IIS host in our dev environment (win server 2012).

below is app.config settings.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="AMPSoapService">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://kcmfsupsd01.na.imtn.com:8080/amp.svc/soap"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="AMPSoapService"
          contract="AMPServiceReference.CoreXmlPort" name="AMPSoapService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is how i access in code:

```
CoreXmlPortClient client = new CoreXmlPortClient();
// Create ship request and append all required parameters
            ShipRequest shipRequest = new ShipRequest();
// Send ship request
            ShipResponse shipResponse = client.Ship(shipRequest);
```

**My Question is:** Timeout exception is thrown in dev, qa and prod environments. This is not consistent.

system.timeoutexception: the http request to 'http://kcmfsupsd01.na.imtn.com/amp.svc/soap http://kcmfsupsd01.na.imtn.com/amp.svc/soap ' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. the time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Not specific to a request. It can happen any request, any time.